A strange usage case of bitwise or operator, why doesn't it work as intended?
I wrote a piece of code which looks like this:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::string, std::cout, std::cin, std::getline;

int main()
{
    string mainStr;
    cout << "Enter expression: ";
    getline(cin, mainStr);
    cout << mainStr.length();

    for (auto el : mainStr)
    {
        if (el == '@' || el == '#' || el == '%' || el == '*' || el == '&') 
        {
            switch (el)
            {
            case '@': cout << "\nfound \'@\'!";
                break;
            case '#': cout << "\nfound \'#\'!";
                break;
            case '%': cout << "\nfound \'%\'!";
                break;
            case '*': cout << "\nfound \'*\'!";
                break;
            case '&': cout << "\nfound \'&\'!";
                break;
            default: cout << "\nerror occured!";
                break;
            }
        }
        else if (el == '(' || el == ')')
        {
            switch (el)
            {
            case '(': cout << "\nfound \'(\'!";
                break;
            case ')': cout << "\nfound \')\'!";
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}


It works as expected.
But then I thought, the if condition looks very long. So I did this:
if (el == ('@' | '#' | '%' | '*' | '&')) {...}
and,
else if (el == ('(' | ')'))
This time it doesn't work. Although, somehow, the closing parenthesis (if present in the mainStr) gets detected.
EDIT: this does not work:
If I did this in Turbo C++, with pure C language, it works.
I use Visual Studio 2022 on Windows 11.
If anyone could tell me why this isn't right and what should be done instead, please, let me know.

Who told you el == ('+' | '-' | '*' | '/' | '^') would work?

Why do you believe the expression el == ('+' | '-' | '*' | '/' | '^') would be equivalent to the expression el == '@' || el == '#' || el == '%' || el == '*' || el == '&'?   Because it is something completely different.

"Although, somehow, the closing paranthesis gets detected." Because '(' | ')' results in ')'. And '+' | '-' | '*' | '/' | '^' results in'\x7F'.

You test el == v where v is ('+' | '-' | '*' | '/' | '^'). Even if you do not know what bitwise or is for, which you obviously don't, how about adding a watch in your debugger to have it evaluate the expression ('+' | '-' | '*' | '/' | '^')? Surely you will see that is not what you want.

Also, in C++, el == ('(' | ')') is not even close to being a shortcut for el == '(' || el == ')'

And I don't see any reason to even use if here and use two switch statements. This could be a single switch statement.

Does this answer your question? Most efficient way to compare a variable to multiple values?

Bitwise or | is not the same as logical or ||. Also "If I did this in Turbo C++..." - forget about Turbo C++, it is about 30 years old, doesn't support standard C++ and has been obsolete for decades; nobody uses it for anything these days (and haven't for ages), using it will teach you nothing but things you'll have to unlearn again.

If you did this with Turbo C++, it did not work then either.

As avid user of TUrbo C++ in past, it would NOT work there either.

...what should be done instead...  The code that you provided that works as expected should be done instead of the bitwise OR code that does not work — even if it was done in pure C code in Turbo C++, it still would not work.

Well, your | is an arithmetic or-operation -- you are just or-ing the codes for the characters, so effectively you're comparing your character with some garbage. There is no special if-syntax like what you're writing.
Now, the funny thing is, look at the ASCII codes (which is all we need to care about nowadays) for the parenthesis, given in binary for your convenience:
'('         00101000 (decimal 40)
')'         00101001 (decimal 41)

'(' | ')'   00101001 (decimal 41)

Note: "or" works bitwise; the result-bit is 1 if either of the source bits is 1, and 0 if both source bits are 0.
As you can see, the result of 'or'-ing the two is the same as the closing ')', which is why that is still detected...

To gre_gor, no one told me it would work, it somehow magically worked in Turbo C++, I don't know how, I am sorry.

To gre_gor, Thank you for the link, it helped me to clear up the huge if condition. And the switch part is me trying to figure out which ones are not getting detected. I am stupid, I know.

To Peter, if the special characters are bothering you, then, I say that I forgot to change them. Sorry.

To Atmo, I do know what Bitwise Or is, at least what there is in the textbook which dates back to a decade ago (which is surprising actually, I was taught that book.), But, I do not know when and where to use it. And about adding a watch in the debugger to have it evaluate the expression, I don't know how! Me beginner.

And for those who told that it doesn't work in Turbo C++, I think you all maybe right, I don't know why it worked for me, maybe it didn't, maybe I was daydreaming.

Since the main question is answered, thanks to Christian Stieber, can someone close this thread? OR maybe, even better, delete this thread forever, like it never happened, I am really ashamed of myself right now, please delete. Guess what? I can delete it myself, wOw!! Nope, I cannot.
